# How to merge two different select query in sql

Tags: mysql

1st query:

```
SELECT orders.order_id,account.username 
    FROM account 
      LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.account_id=account.account_id
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT items.item_name 
   FROM order_items 
   LEFT JOIN items ON items.item_id=order_items.item_id
```

Comment: Use the concept of [Unions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: Please, explain "_merge_".

Comment: You joined the tables in 1st query. Copy the concept.

Comment: sir i tried a lot but didnt get the answer i am new in sql please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
       orders.order_id,
       account.username,
       items.item_name
FROM account 
     LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.account_id=account.account_id
     LEFT JOIN order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
     LEFT JOIN items ON items.item_id=order_items.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT orders.order_id,account.username, items.item_name 
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN orders on orders.account_id=account.account_id
left join order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
left join items on items.item_id=order_items.item_id
```